# Can deuterium be separated from heavy water via electrolysis? It is an isotope of hydrogen, so I guess it should act in the same way?

Tags: electrochemistry, water, electrolysis, hydrogen, isotope

I was wondering if it is possible to separate deuterium from heavy water via electrolysis.
Also, is this the way deuterium gas is obtained on an industrial scale, or are there better methods?

Comment: See https://www.iter.org/newsline/167/631 for example.

Comment: All hydrogen of heavy water is deuterium. It's electrolysis separates deuterium and oxygen.

Comment: Yes, Deuterium can be separated from heavy water  $\ce{D2O}$ by electrolysis. I don't know whether it is the best way of producing $\ce{D2}$.

Comment: Why would anyone produce deuterium gas on an industrial scale?

Comment: @Karl - because there is a demand for it for various things, from nuclear physics to bio-tagging molecules.

Comment: If by chance you are asking about separating deuterons and protons from water that has both, electrolysis can indeed be used for that, since the hydrogen gas produced is enriched in protium due to the isotope effects: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0360319921029591

Comment: @JonCuster Sounds rather like lab-scale demands, not industrial.

Comment: @Karl - Canada exports roughly $30M of heavy water a year as the top producer. Not a commodity chemical, but not exactly lab scale either.

Comment: @JonCuster Yea, you need tons of it to run certain types of nuclear reactors, for starters. And to produce any kind of deuterated chemicals, which is pretty large market, etc. I was talking about deuterium *gas*. What is that good for? A few university labs and a very small number of speciality chemical companies buy a five-liter gas bottle per year, I expect.